# How to capture form errors in Sign In page using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication and the sign in form uses flash notices instead of form errors to display any issues when signing in. But I want to highlight the appropriate form fields that have associated errors like normally happens in rails forms. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you already seen this http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise and this http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise ?

Comment: I've seen those. It still shows one error for the whole login form.

Answer (score 1):

The default Devise errors function for devise 1.1.5 can be found in the devise gem:

devise-1.1.5/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = "#{pluralize(resource.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this #{resource_name} from being saved:"

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

I suppose you could overwrite this module/function if you wanted it to behave differently.

Comment: This didnt work for me. No error messages were produced. Perhaps things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Rails version (prior to 3 or not), you could use:

```
<%= f.error_messages_for :model %>
```

Rails version before the 3.0 use this code to handle and format errors. In Rails 3 this method has become it's deprecated. You need to install this [plugin](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form) to use the erb code above.

You can read more details about this change under the "The New Features" chapter of [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) asciicast.

[This tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) covers the entire process of building an authentication system based on devise and cancan.

Comment: My question is more specific to the way the devise sign in form works. The problem is it doesn't add error messages that way in this form, it just sets a flash notice. That's what I'm trying to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are stored in a map:

```
resource.errors
```

If your form field called `:email`, you may get associated error like this:

```
resource.errors[:email]
```

Comment: This is exaclty what devise does NOT does ¬¬

Comment: What do you mean? Errors not stored in resource.errors or you can't get them with resource.error[:email]? One year ago they were there.

Comment: The error raised when a user input his wrong credentials is "Invalid username or password", for good practice reasons. Thus, there is no way to attribute the error for one or other field.